# Getting parent key in a nested array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, nested

I'm building a "nested" array fetching from database; here's my script:

```
while ($row_rsMaster = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMaster)) {
    $numbers[] = array("Page ");
}
```

I'd like to obtain the following array (with print_r() function), but I'm totally stuck on how to get the page number:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Page 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Page 2
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Page 3
            [1] => 3
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Page 4
            [1] => 4
        )

)
```

I tried:

```
$numbers[] = array("Pagina " . key($numbers)+1, key($numbers)+1);
```

but it didn't lead to expected results (in my mind, it should get the current key number of the "parent" array and increment by 1)

Please, any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you putting the page numbers in the same array $numbers[]?

Comment: I need to json encode that array to get someting like tthat: [["Page 1", 1], ["Page 2", 2], ["Page 3", 3]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count by your own:

```
$n = 0;
while ($row_rsMaster = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMaster)) {
    $n++;
    $numbers[] = array("Page ".$n, $n);
}
```

Or, use `count($numbers)+1` in your code:

```
while ($row_rsMaster = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMaster)) {
    $numbers[] = array("Page ".(count($numbers)+1), count($numbers)+1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking to use a counter, but I was wondering if there's a counter-less solution... is it possible?

Comment: Well, when you get count($numbers), you still use counter. Its internal of php, but it still there.

Comment: Yeah, we are almost there!!! It's all fine with the second solution, except that the "Pagina".count($numbers)+1 gets converted in a number... mmm... strange

Comment: oh, forget for additional brackets: "Page ".(count($numbers)+1). Or, separate variable as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to datacompboy I finally came to this:

```
while ($row_rsMaster = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMaster)) {
    $counter = count($numbers)+1;
    $numbers[] = array("Page " . $counter, $counter);
}
```